# Generic placeholders or default values in Rust

Tags: generics, error-handling, rust, default

I'm trying to write a generic command line parser. I'm having trouble with "default" values for generic types. `cmd.invoke()` returns a `Result<K, E>`, so there's no problem there, but how do I represent a placeholder or default value for `E` when `cmd_to_invoke` is a `None`? In C#, I could use `default(E)`. Is there a construct like this in Rust?

```
pub struct Cmd<K, E> {
    cmds: Vec<Cmd<K, E>>,
}

impl<K, E> Cmd<K, E> {
    pub fn invoke(&mut self, cmd_name: &str) -> Result<K, E> {
        let cmd_to_invoke = self.cmds.iter_mut().find(|cmd| cmd.name == cmd_name);
        if let Some(cmd) = cmd_to_invoke {
            cmd.invoke()
        } else {
            // Some default / placeholder value for E
            Err(/* ? */)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the `Default` trait: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably are looking for [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html).

For example:

```
pub struct Cmd<K, E> {}

impl<K, E: Default> Cmd<K, E> {
    pub fn invoke(&mut self, cmd_name: &str) -> Result<K, E> {
        let cmd_to_invoke = self.cmds.iter_mut().find(|cmd| cmd.name == cmd_name);
        if let Some(cmd) = cmd_to_invoke {
            cmd.invoke()
        } else {
            // Some default / placeholder value for E
            Err(Default::default())
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting though that most error types in `std` and popular crates do not implement `Default`.

The idiomatic way of dealing with multiple error types in Rust is to define your own error `enum` for your application, library or component, which implements `From` for each possible underlying error type. This generally makes code simpler and easier to read, and works very nicely with the `?` operator. [Here is an example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#examples).

If you are writing a library which really must work with *any* error type, then this won't work. In that case, you are probably left with constraining `E` to the `std::error::Error` trait and then making a custom error type which can be converted from that, possibly keeping reference to the underlying error as a trait object.